# How to add custom tab to cms pages tab panel in custom module magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can i add extra tab for cms tabs menu on edit page of cms block using my custom module.Can anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your custom module? Place it in github and give a link here, then maybe we can help.

Comment: Sorry i am working on local machine.

Comment: I find solution simply rewrite :
 <rewrite>
             <cms_page_edit_tabs>MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_MyModule_Edit_Tabs</cms_page_edit_tabs>
         </rewrite>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use layout and add your own block to the tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">
    <adminhtml_cms_page_edit>
        <reference name="cms_page_edit_tabs">
            <block type="module/cms_page_edit_tab_tags" name="cms_page_edit_tab_tags" after="cms_page_edit_tab_meta"/>                
            <action method="addTab"><name>tags_section</name><block>cms_page_edit_tab_tags</block></action>                                
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_cms_page_edit>
</layout>
```

and block implementation

```
class My_Module_Block_Cms_Page_Edit_Tab_Tags 
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        // your tab code here
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return Mage::helper('cms')->__('Cms Pages Products');
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return Mage::helper('cms')->__('Cms Pages Products');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Look at app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/* and app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml for implementation

Comment: Thanks Parvel.But I think the method i follow is easy way , that when i added tab then this tab  call my block code like 
 $this->addTab('form_section', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('New Tab'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('New Tab'),
                   'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
      ));
What you say about it.

Comment: Just one question: what if one day you install extension that adds tab same way as you did it? I prefer not to use rewrites if it can be avoided

Comment: Thanks i didn't think about it.